# Docstring in the function based view

Tags: django, swagger

how to add docstring to function based view so that it can be visible in the swagger UI? I have created a manual schema for each my API and its working through swagger but I need to add docstring as well example responses in the Swagger UI.
This is how I am trying. But no use.

```
**schema.py**
MySwagger=ManualSchema(fields=

[coreapi.Field(name="data", required=True, location="form",

type="array",description="list of preprocessing here",)],)


**view.py**

@api_view(['POST'])
@schema(MySwagger)
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer])
def myView(requests):
"""
enter code here
View description here
"""
--code--


**url.py**
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')
pref='api/v1/'
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url('^$',schema_view,name="swagger"),
url(pref+'callMyView$',views.myView,name ='autoMLTrainModel')
]
```

Comment: Please add anything you have already tried, expectations, what was returned, etc.

Comment: I treid normal doctring syntax in my function based view.

Comment: What does "normal docstring syntax" even mean? Put what you did so we can see what you (apparently) did wrong. We simply cannot help otherwise. 

Example - You go to a doctor, doctor says what's wrong. You say "I have an itch". Doctor says "Where?" You say "In the itchy bit."

Comment: i have added an example below.

Comment: Ok did that answer your question?

Comment: the description is not showing in the swagger UI.

Comment: Ok so it's not an answer then. Please remove it. Is this _your_ code?

Comment: yes, this my code. this is how I am trying to show the description in the Swagger UI. But it doesn't work

Comment: Add this to your question, not an answer.

Comment: done. Now do you have the answer?